# Slick can't be detected inside another function?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm having trouble with [slick,](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) specifically, how it's being processed inside another function. I tried looking around for a bit, but I wasn't able to find similar answers yet.

The code below works just fine when called as is,

```
$('.thisBagGallery').slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  variableHeight: true,
  centerPadding: '100px',
  slidesToShow: 1
});
```

But then calling `$('.thisBagGallery').slick();` elsewhere,

```
$("#newBag").click(function(){
  $("#bag0Meta").append($("#clsImgLnk0"));
  $("#bag0Meta").append($("#opnImgLnk0"));
  $("#bag0Meta").append($("#sclImgLnk0"));
  $("#bag0Meta").append($("#thisBagTitle0"));
  $("#bag0Meta").append($("#thisBagDescription0"));
  $(".thisBagGallery").slick('unslick');
});
```

Gives me `TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function`

Comment: make sure `.thisBagGallery` exist and you are importing the library

Comment: The class already exists, `<div id="thisBagViewer" class="thisBagGallery justify-content-center align-items-center">content</div>` , and the dependencies have already been added in on the main html. Still nothing.